# Store file content into arrays

Tags: bash

What i'm trying to do is to take content form the file "test" modify it and display it again.

**So the test file looks like this:**

```
test
test.com
```

**And i want to modify it, so it would look like this:**

```
DNS.1 = test
DNS.2 = test.com
```

**so i am trying to it with something like this:**

```
$(i=1
for alt in "${alts[@]}"; do
    echo "DNS.$((i++)) = $alt"
done)
```

I just don't have an idea how i could take the content from a file and connect it with the code right above.

Does someone has an idea how it could work or knows where i can search for that problem.

Comment: With awk: `awk '{print "DNS." NR " = " $0}' file`

Comment: or `awk '$0="DNS." NR " = " $0' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there are better ways than a loop when your input is a file. However, if you really want an array use `mapfile`:

```
< file mapfile -t alts

echo "array alts has ${!alts[@]} entries"
echo "the entries are"
printf '"%s\n"' "${alts[@]}"
```

By the way: Cyrus' `awk` script can also be used when your input is not a file but just an array:

```
# for files
awk '{print "DNS." NR " = " $0}' file
```

```
# for arrays (use only if your input is not a file)
(IFS=$'\n'; awk '{print "DNS." NR " = " $0}' <<< "${array[*]}")
# or
awk '{print "DNS." NR " = " $0}' < <(printf %s\\n "${array[@]}")
```

Comment: Thanks alot you helped me a second time.